# How to compare a property to the values from an array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, d3.js

**d** :  `{"children":[{"name":"China","children":[{"name":"China","value":400,"percentage":"33.33"}],"index":0},{"name":"England","children":[{"name":"England","value":300,"percentage":"33.33"}],"index":1},{"name":"Malaysia","children":[{"name":"Malaysia","value":500,"percentage":"25.00"}],"index":2},{"name":"South Korea","children":[{"name":"South Korea","value":600,"percentage":"50.00"}],"index":3}]}`

**Array of object**

```
cfg.thresholdSetting.thresholds = [{"dType":"threshold","from":0,"to":30,"color":"rgb(217, 20 ,39)"},{"dType":"threshold","from":30,"to":70,"color":"rgb(242, 145, 10)"},{"dType":"threshold","from":70,"to":120,"color":"rgb(33, 145, 49)"}]
```

Then I have a property  :

```
rect.style("fill", function (d, i) {

    for (var k = 0; k < fromValues.length; k++) {
      console.log("percentage : " + d.percentage)
      console.log("from value : " + fromValues[k])
      console.log("to value : " + toValues[k])
         if (d.percentage >= fromValues[k] && d.percentage <= toValues[k]) {
           return cfg.thresholdSetting.thresholds[k].color;
         }
         else {
           return "#808080";
         } 
    }
  })
```

From the code , My output for the from and to values is stagnant and not moving. The outer loop runs according to the number of data that I have. How do I compare these values?

**Current Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

```
d.percentage = 33.33
from value   = 0
to value     = 30

d.percentage = 33.33
from value   = 30
to value     = 70

d.percentage = 33.33
from value   = 70
to value     = 120 

d.percentage = 50.00
from value   = 0
to value     = 30

d.percentage = 50.00
from value   = 30
to value     = 70

d.percentage = 50.00
from value   = 70
to value     = 120
```

Comment: where is `d` coming from? why do you exit the loop in the first iteration?

Comment: d is the iterator for my data, which means that it will loop according to the number of data that I have, what do you mean exit? I dont understand? returning a value exits the loop is it? How do I return a value in a loop then? @NinaScholz

Comment: yes, `return` exits not only the loop, but the whole function.

Comment: okay so how do I go about then to get my expected output?

Comment: still `d` is missing.

Comment: added the d and my current output @NinaScholz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180923/discussion-between-syed-ariff-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, I assume you are using d3, and you want to set the color of the rectangle according to which bin they are. I also assume `"#808080"` is a default color when the data does not match any bin. In this case:

```
rect.style("fill", function(d) {
    var color = cfg.thresholdSetting.thresholds.filter(function(t, i) {
        return d.percentage >= t.from && d.percentage < t.to;
    });
    return color.length > 0 ? color[0].color : "#808080";
});
```

Comment: the color should be thresholdSetting.thresholds.color.

Comment: how likely is it that you get more than 1 range record?

Comment: It is not possible, this is why I compare the value with open boundary with `t.to`. Depends on what the default value is: if it should be the color corresponding to the lowest possible range, it should be `d.percentage > t.from && d.percentage <= t.to`, otherwise the one in my answer.